# Convert decimal to binary in matlab

Tags: matlab

If I use a decimal to binary command in Matlab how can I get the result in four digits? e.g. 7 =0111 or 2=0010.
Thanks in advance

Othman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `dec2bin`:

```
str = dec2bin(7)   // 0111
str = dec2bin(7,8) // 00000111, pad the result to 8 bits
```